# How to best implement countWhile in Haskell for vectors?

Tags: haskell, vector

I'd like to use a function that counts the number of items at the beginning of a [Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector.html) that satisfies a predicate. In other words:

```
countWhile p xs = V.length $ V.takeWhile p xs
```

Would stream fusion optimize this function or is it more efficient write out the recursion explicitly, like the following?

```
countWhile p xs
  | V.null xs = 0
  | otherwise = if p (V.head xs) then 1 + countWhile p (V.tail xs) else 0
```

Or is there another better way?

Comment: I would expect that to be optimized away by stream fusion, yes.  You can always check with `ghc-core` and looking at the optimized Core yourself.

Answer (score 4):

There's already a function [`findIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.12.2/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:findIndex) for finding the index of the first item that does satisfy a predicate.

```
findIndex :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a -> Maybe Int
```

Assuming this is as efficient as possible, we could use this to efficiently write `countWhile` by finding the first index that doesn't match the predicate. If we can't find one that doesn't match the predicate then all of them (`length v`) matched the predicate.

```
countWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a -> Int
countWhile p v = maybe (length v) (findIndex (not . p) v)
```